# Haskell function to apply operations recursively to an argument

Tags: haskell, ghc

**Is there a built-in function in Haskell to apply a list of operations recursively to an argument?**

I have a list of operations to apply to a `Double` (multiplication, addition, ...) and I would like simply to get the result.
For example :

```
operationList = [
                  (\v -> v/8+2)
                , (\v -> v-12)
                , (\v -> v*v)
                ]

func operationList 3
```

`func` should return `92,640625`.

I searched in hoogle the signature `[(a -> a)] -> a -> a` but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to solve this problem. One is to apply each function to the result of applying the previous function. This gives you:

```
foldr ($) 3 (reverse operationList)
```

The other is to first compose all the functions together and then to apply the resulting function to the argument:

```
foldr (.) id (reverse operationList) 3
```

This behavior of functions under composition is also captured by the `Endo` monoid:

```
appEndo (foldMap Endo (reverse operationList)) 3
```

The list must be reversed because foldr folds from "right to left":

```
foldr ($) 3 [f,g,h]
= { definition of foldr }
f $ g $ h $ 3
= { definition of ($) }
f (g (h 3))

foldr (.) id [f,g,h] 3
= { definition of foldr }
(f . g . h . id) 3
= { definition of (.), definition of id, eta reduction }
f (g (h 3))
```

Comment: You should never have to reverse a list to fold over it. `foldr f n (reverse xs) = foldl (flip f) n xs` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: And I believe `foldMap (Dual . Endo)` is the way to do it with `Foldable`.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, but conceptually the `foldl` version is much more complicated. I wanted to get at the underlying concept rather than get stuck on administrivia. The `Dual` version is rather nice though. Also I suspected that OP would have control over the list order in a real application so a reverse wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

```
\> foldr ($) 3 (reverse operationList)
92.640625
```

or

```
\> foldl (flip ($)) 3 operationList
92.640625
```